# Complex Table in Tailwind

Tags: html, tailwind-css

How can I make this table on TailWind? I am having some issues creating the table.

Table Sample:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th colspan=2>Mars</th>
    <th colspan=2>Venus</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Produced</th>
    <th>Sold</th>
    <th>Produced</th>
    <th>Sold</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Teddy Bears</td>
    <td>50,000</td>
    <td>30,000</td>
    <td>100,000</td>
    <td>80,000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Board Games</td>
    <td>10,000</td>
    <td>5,000</td>
    <td>12,000</td>
    <td>9,000</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

table {
  @apply border-collapse  text-gray-700;
}

tr > * {
  @apply border border-gray-400;
}

th {
  @apply bg-gray-200 text-left;
}

td {
  @apply bg-gray-100 text-right;
}
```

[Working example](https://play.tailwindcss.com/RYshbC4oHJ)